# How to set accountExpires

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, active-directory

```
dirEntry.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = val & ~0x2; //enable user
//above line no error but below line get error
dirEntry.Properties["accountExpires"].Value = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1).ToFileTimeUtc();
```

> The error thrown is errMsg =
>   "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Unspecified
>   error\r\n\r\n   at
>   System.DirectoryServices.Interop.UnsafeNativeMethods.IAds.PutEx(Int32
>   lnControlCode, String bstrName, Object vProp)\r\n   at
>   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueColl...

Please advise. If it was a permission issue I would have gotten an error on the first line ... On premise AD (not Azure) Thanks

Comment: Try `Convert.ToString((Int64)DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1).ToFileTimeUtc())` before assigning the same to accountExpires value.

Comment: BTW, are you a fan of Gulshan Grover (or actually Gulshan Grover)? Just asking.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful, That worked !. Thanks for your help and yes big fan of Gullu bhai. They don't make good bad guys like Gullu, Shakti, Ranjeet , Prem Chopra, Ajit etc these days..

Comment: Please leave an answer for future visitors on what you did which helped you resolve the problem! Cheers :).

Answer (score 3):

For those who come here with the same issue, this fixed it . . .

```
Convert.ToString((Int64)DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1).ToFileTimeUtc())
```

See [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/c8b69956-2f40-472b-a9a3-33d0046cb911/accountexpires-set-error-help?forum=WindowsAzureAD) for a more detailed discussion.